# imagePickerController broken in Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

After upgrading to latest Xcode 6.3, the imagePickerController no longer works. Any idea what's the latest changes to this method?

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: NSDictionary!) {...} 

Error message:
'imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:' provided by method 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' in protocol 'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you are using wrong function, instead of that, please use this!

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
//Your Code
}
```

Comment: Seems to be right, but the behaviour changed? Used to be select a picture the picker will go away, now select it and nothing happened until press Cancel.

Comment: Put this line under the function: `picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)`

Comment: Hope you have implemented function: `func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController`

Comment: If I don't do anything for cancel, do I still need to implement imagePickerControllerDidCancel?

Comment: Of course, just add this func to your code `func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController){
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }`

Comment: Whats the difference with adding an empty function and not adding?

Comment: Can you please specify which is an empty function here?

Comment: Nothing is happening if user press Cancel... so why should we need to implement imagePickerControllerDidCancel which do nothing?

Comment: imagePickerControllerDidCancel is not empty. If you press cancel then the ImagePickerController will be dismissed from your screen. You need to implement `picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` in your `imagePickerControllerDidCancel ` function

Comment: That's the part that I don't understand. I didn't implement that right now, and cancel it still go away, just like it is intended?

Comment: See my second comment, I hope you have implemented that line in your code, that's the reason it goes away!

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue with you,and I did as below,and it works now.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let pickedImage: UIImage = (info as NSDictionary).objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as! UIImage
    let smallPicture = scaleImageWith(pickedImage, newSize: CGSizeMake(250, 250))
    var sizeOfImageView:CGRect = itemImageView.frame
    sizeOfImageView.size = smallPicture.size
    itemImageView.frame = sizeOfImageView
    itemImageView.image = smallPicture
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method in Swift 2

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, 
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
```